# Setting up filtering for a subnet behind a corporate proxy

Tags: proxy, webfilter

My (all Windows) office is hooked into a corporate LAN in a remote city. We're accessing the Internet via the corporate proxy server on their end.

For political reasons, there is not and will not be any filtering on the corporate proxy. But my team wants filtering.

Is there any way that we could set up a filtering solution from behind the proxy? Either workstation-by-workstation or full subnet solutions could work.

We would be willing to invest a small amount of money, too; less than 100$ would probably be fine.

(go lightly, please... I'm very far from a networking pro!)

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy a Squid proxy with in your LAN and setup the corporate proxy as its parent. As web filtering solution for Squid I recommend qlproxy. That will let you specify possibly different filtering settings by user name, workstation ip or whole subnet.

It runs on Linux/FreeBSD though - so may be this would require a little administrative efforts.

Comment: Probably not realistic for us to be running a non-Windows machine here, but the idea of having a Squid proxy seems a good one

Comment: There is a prebuilt vm with everything on quintolabs site, some admins use it in hyper-v after converting from vmware, maybe worth a try (web ui is included so almost no need to work from command line)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you intend to do your content filtering, your LAN setup and policies.

A typical solution would be to point your users to a local web proxy which does your content filtering and which forwards all allowed requests to your corporate proxy server.

Squid is popular Open Source proxy server and also the engine included in a number of commercial solutions. The [cache_peer](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/) configuration option is used to chain your local proxy and to forward all requests to the corporate proxy server. From the manual:

```
#                                        proxy  icp
#          hostname             type     port   port  options
#          -------------------- -------- ----- -----  -----------
cache_peer parent.foo.net       parent    3128  0     default
```

Potential issues are (forwarding) authentication requirements, logging, caching and management.

Comment: If machines from outside our local proxy are seeing us through a proxy, will that be an issue for (eg) RDP to our machines from theirs?

Comment: A proxy server would typicaly be used only for web browsing i.e. HTTP, HTTPS and FTP. It will not be relevant for other protocols, such as remote dekstop.